# DropDownCount not working with OwnerDrawFixed style

Tags: delphi

I have a `TComboBox` with `csOwnerDrawFixed` style.

I've set the `DropDownCount` to 20.  When there are many items in the list, it is only showing 16.

When there are 2 items in the list, it only shows one, with a scrollbar to select the other.

When there is only one item in the list, the DropDown is completely empty!

How can I fix this?

*I am asking the question and giving the answer.  I spent hours looking for the solution and eventually found the answer after getting a clue from a post on some other web site. I thought I would put my answer here so that future visitors with the same problem can find the answer easily.*

Comment: This other post should have a pointer to this one, but I don't know how to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35122957/delphi-seattle-tcombobox-dropdowncount-not-working-when-using-ownerdraw-style

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case I had an `OnMeasureItem` event handler that returns `Height := 19;`

But my `ItemHeight` property was set to 16.

The DropDown would be made large enough to hold 20 items that are each 16-pixels tall, but since each item was 19, that only left room for 16 items to be shown.

I solved the problem by setting `ItemHeight` to 19, to match my `OnMeasureItem` event.